# Set up RDS on multiple servers using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, installation, rds, windows-server-2012-r2

A follow-on to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/566346/splitting-up-rds-roles).

I've installed an RDS Gateway and Connection Broker on one host, and Session Host on a second dedicated host:

Server A (colombes):

```
Add-WindowsFeature –Name RDS-Gateway –IncludeAllSubFeature
Add-WindowsFeature –Name RDS-Connection-Broker –IncludeAllSubFeature
```

Server B (dunkirk):

```
Add-WindowsFeature –Name RDS-RD-Server –IncludeAllSubFeature
```

Server Manager on Server A shows this:

[image]

And on Server B it shows:

[image]

Clearly I've missed the step that gets the two servers talking to each other properly, how can this be done with PowerShell alone? They can 'see' each other, so it isn't that they aren't communicating at all:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this:

```
import-module RemoteDesktop
New-SessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker "colombes.fqdn" -SessionHost "dunkirk.fqdn"
```

There's some good info on the topic here: [Deploying a Session Based Desktop Deployment Using PowerShell on Windows Server 2012](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12834.deploying-a-session-based-desktop-deployment-using-powershell-on-windows-server-2012.aspx)

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks. I'd seen that guide but not read through it properly (maybe because of the small writing!).

Comment: You can use Ctrl+ to make small writing bigger :-)